# Retrieve a task result object, given a `task_id` in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I store the `task_id` from an `celery.result.AsyncResult` in a database and relate it to the item that the task affects. This allows me to perform a query to retrieve all the `task_id`s of tasks that relate to a specific item.

So after retrieving the `task_id` from the database, how do I go about retrieving information about the task's state/result/etc?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From the [Celery FAQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-task-if-i-have-the-id-that-points-there):

```
result = MyTask.AsyncResult(task_id)
result.get()
```

Comment: Note this won't work in testing (i.e. if `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` is `True`). See https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2275

Comment: Reference an example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753040/retrieve-task-result-by-id-in-celery