# Retrieving GroupResult from taskset_id in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am starting a set of celery tasks by using celery group as described in the [official documentation](http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/tasksets.html#groups)

I am also storing the group (taskset) id into a db, in order to poll celery for the taskset state.

```
job = group([
        single_test.s(1, 1),
        single_test.s(1, 2),
        single_test.s(1, 3),
    ])

result = job.apply_async()

test_set = MyTestSet()
test_set.taskset_id = result.id

# store test_set into DB
```

Is there a way to obtain a GroupResult object (i.e. my `result`) starting from the taskset id?
Something like what is done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544611/retrieve-a-task-result-object-given-a-task-id-in-celery), but working with celery groups.

I already tried doing:

```
r = GroupResult(taskset_id)
```

but it does not work, as `r.results()` is always empty.

Should I use `GroupResult.save()` and `GroupResult.restore()` [methods](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.GroupResult)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you have to save the result and then restore it.

```
job = group([
    single_test.s(1, 1),
    single_test.s(1, 2),
    single_test.s(1, 3),
])
result = job.apply_async()
result.save()

from celery.result import GroupResult
saved_result = GroupResult.restore(result.id)
```

I had the same issue and after seeing your hint about save/restore eventually figured it out.

Comment: In celery 4.1.0 (latentcall) you have to pass an app instance to the restore method:  GroupResult.restore(result.id, app=group.app)