# Attempting to retrieve a Celery GroupResult using ID, with an AMQP backend

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I'm running into a really vexing issue when using Celery with RabbitMQ.

I have something like:

```
from celery import group
group_of_tasks = group(task.s(x) for x in job_list)
result = group_of_tasks.delay()
print result.id  # let's call this d453359d...
```

The above works fine, no issues, I can query the states of the group as well as the individual AsyncResults in result.results.

However, if I try to, in a separate console, do the following:

```
from celery.result import GroupResult
x = GroupResult.restore('d453359d...')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py", line 806, in restore
     ).restore_group(id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\amqp.py", line 297, in restore_group
    'restore_group is not supported by this backend.')
NotImplementedError: restore_group is not supported by this backend.
```

I came across a similar question in [Retrieving GroupResult from taskset_id in Celery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685344/retrieving-groupresult-from-taskset-id-in-celery), where the `.save` is mentioned, but using that also results in a `NotImplementedError` being thrown.

The source for the AMQP backend defined in celery.backends.amqp has the following:

```
def save_group(self, group_id, result):
    raise NotImplementedError(
        'save_group is not supported by this backend.')

def restore_group(self, group_id, cache=True):
    raise NotImplementedError(
        'restore_group is not supported by this backend.')
```

So, my question is, is there no way for me to recreate a group of results using just the `GroupResult` ID? The only way to do it would be to store the IDs of each of the `AsyncResults` in the group and query each one?

Or am I just missing something very obvious here?

I'm running Celery on Python 2.7.10 on Windows, using RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - you cannot recreate the group of results while using RabbitMQ - you will need to use a different results backend that does support this action, such as Redis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had a feeling there was no way with AMQP (I'll have to stick with that because we need reliability and persistence), but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: you do realise that redis offers [persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) and [replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication), right?

Comment: Wow. This is why I love SO. Thanks for those links, @scytale, I'll take a look and see if Redis would make more sense for this project.

Comment: I'd recommend rabbitmq for the broker and redis for the results backend