# Retrieve task result by id in Celery

Tags: celery

I am trying to retreive the result of a task which has completed.
**This works**

```
from proj.tasks import add
res = add.delay(3,4)
res.get()
7
res.status
'SUCCESS'
res.id
'0d4b36e3-a503-45e4-9125-cfec0a7dca30'
```

But I want to run this from another application. So I rerun python shell and try:

```
from proj.tasks import add
res = add.AsyncResult('0d4b36e3-a503-45e4-9125-cfec0a7dca30')
res.status
'PENDING'
res.get() # Error
```

How can I retrieve the result?

Comment: What are you using as a broker/backend?

Comment: I am using the standard configuration of the tutorials. The broker/backend is RabbitMQ

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It works using `AsyncResult`. (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391054/retrieve-result-from-task-id-in-celery-from-unknown-task))

So first create the task:

```py
from cel.tasks import add

res = add.delay(3,4)
print(res.status) # 'SUCCESS'
print(res.id) # '432890aa-4f02-437d-aaca-1999b70efe8d'
```

Then start another python shell:

```py
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from cel.tasks import app

res = AsyncResult('432890aa-4f02-437d-aaca-1999b70efe8d',app=app)

print(res.state) # 'SUCCESS'
print(res.get()) # 7
```

Comment: Just adding a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544611/retrieve-a-task-result-object-given-a-task-id-in-celery

Comment: I like this answer better than the one in the reference by ItayB. Thanks for adding the reference.

Comment: I was just toying with the example, and noticed that my state changed from 'SUCCESS' to 'PENDING' after the task cleared the queue. Reference state at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#std:state-PENDING to realize your task may have completed, and now the task_id has expired yielding the unknown state.

Comment: @zerocog The same happens when passing non-existing `id` values to `AsyncResult`, i.e. `app.AsyncResult("this-is-no-id").status` is `PENDING` which I found somewhat irritating. An exception would have been more helpful. Both `ready()` and `failed()` return False.

Comment: In my experience I had to put the task before AsyncResult. Like this: `my_task.AsyncResult('taskid...')` Nothing else worked for me.

Comment: For me I needed to add "celery-task-meta-" in front of task id when I search in redis backend.

Answer (score 11):

This is due to RabbitMQ [not actually storing the results](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#rabbitmq-result-backend). If you need the ability to get the results later on, use redis or SQL as the result backend.

Comment: Thank you for the link. What you say seems to be the case, however, I managed to do it (see my answer). This makes me think though because according to what the documentation says (what you linked) it shouldn't work.