# How to get the result from async function in python/Django using Celery + Redis

Tags: django, python-3.x, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

I am new to task queue. When i open the shell and execute the function `add.delay(3,4)` from the function in the shell to perform the task. I get : `<AsyncResult: 30db3528-5b0f-4e74-bf47-51956a1f83e9>`. How do I get a result from this function and what should i do to schedule the result to be executed 5 second later?

**#celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('RedisQueue')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

`@app.task
def add(a, b):
    return a + b`
```

**#__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

**#settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']

CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve task result by id in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753040/retrieve-task-result-by-id-in-celery)

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I am using **Redis** with Celery and the possible duplicate article is based on **RabbitMQ.**

Comment: Did you try res.get()  and you can do time.sleep(5000)  to pause for 5 seconds. In a thread in you don't want blocking code

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Yes I did try `res.get()`. For some strange reason when i use it in the shell, there is no output as if the system is waiting for some instructions. Then when i type `res.status`. the output displayed is **'PENDING'**

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I forgot to execute `Celery -A <mysite> worker -l info` in other terminal.