# Waiting for result of celery task in 2 places get stuck

Tags: python, django, redis, task, celery

I'm using Django, Celery and Redis to execute tasks.

```
# settings.py

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_APP = "my_app"
```

```
# tasks.py

@task(name="my_task", track_started = True)
def my_task():
    time.sleep(5)
    # Do stuff
    return True
```

I call this task in 2 differents places in the application :

```
# test1.py

task = my_task.delay()
result = task.get()
print(result) # Shows True after 5 seconds
```

```
# test2.py

task = AsyncResult(my_task_id)
print(task.status) # Shows STARTED
print(task) # Shows the right id
result = task.get() # Get stuck here
print(result) # This line never appears in console
```

Of course, script in test1.py is called before test2.py. And I'm sure that id is correct. I don't have any messages in celery's log or in Django. It just get stuck.

I already tried solutions described here :
[Retrieve task result by id in Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753040/retrieve-task-result-by-id-in-celery)

Comment: Do you have result backend?

Comment: Yes I have. I edited my question

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Celery 4.4.2 that I use here...

Comment: I am also using Celery 4.4.2. Strange