# Celery distribution task cannot receive the result while backend is set up

Tags: docker, celery

I am trying to implement an MLOps app with building up a celery worker in docker containers, and trying to send task message from local environment. There are three containers:

- multi_label_text_classification_celery_server_1

  - for training and inference
- multi_label_text_classification_redis_1
- multi_label_text_classification_triton_server_1

I have tested the inference task, and it can be called remotely with below:

```
    dataset = pd.read_json('data.json')
    data = dataset.text.values.tolist()
    j_string = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)

    predict_task = predict.apply_async(
        args=(
            'audience_bert',
            1,
            100,
            j_string
        )
    )
    print(predict_task)
```

`task_id`: `758d7455-af2d-494e-8ba9-f9e502a8727c`

[image]

Yet when I have tried to check the status and get the result:

```
result = AsyncResult(task_id)
print(result.state)
print(result.get())
```

it shows up the error `DisabledBackend` but I have already set up both backends in container and local celery app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ychuang\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\celery-client-HqyYFMWr-py3.8\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py", line 478, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']
  File "C:\Users\ychuang\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\celery-client-HqyYFMWr-py3.8\lib\site-packages\celery\result.py", line 417, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "C:\Users\ychuang\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\celery-client-HqyYFMWr-py3.8\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\base.py", line 609, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

I have looking for the probable reason that caused the `DisabledBackend`, while lots of the similar posts are about missing `backend`.
Please, could anyone help me out?

Below are my docker-compose file and celery code:

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  celery_server:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - models:/model/torch_script
    environment:
      LEVEL: ${LEVEL}
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  triton_server:
    image: nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:22.06-py3
    hostname: triton
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8001:8001
      - 8002:8002
    command: ["tritonserver", "--model-store=/models", "--model-control-mode=poll", --repository-poll-secs=30]
    volumes:
      - models:/models
    shm_size: 1g
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
      stack: 67108864

volumes:
  models:
```

- container worker

```
import json
from typing import Dict

from celery import Celery

from config.settings import MODEL_CKPT, LogDir
from utils.inference_helper import chunks
from utils.log_helper import create_logger
from worker.inference.bert_triton_inference import BertInferenceWorker
from worker.train.chinese_bert_classification import ChineseBertClassification

app = Celery(
    name='bert_celery',
    broker="redis://redis:6379/0",
    backend="redis://redis:6379/1"
)

app.conf.task_routes = {
    'app.*': {'queue': 'deep_model'},
}

app.conf.update(result_expires=1)
app.conf.update(task_track_started=True)


@app.task(bind=True, queue='deep_model', name='training')
def training(
        self,
        model_name,
        version,
        dataset,
        label_col,
        learning_rate=2e-5,
        epochs=50,
        batch_size=32,
        max_len=30,
        is_multi_label=1,
        ckpt=MODEL_CKPT.get('chinese-bert-wwm')

):
    dataset = json.loads(dataset)
    label_col = json.loads(label_col)

    task_worker = ChineseBertClassification(
        max_len=max_len,
        ckpt=ckpt,
        epochs=epochs,
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        dataset=dataset,
        label_col=label_col,
        model_name=model_name,
        model_version=version,
        is_multi_label=is_multi_label
    )

    task_worker.init_model()
    results: Dict[str, str] = task_worker.run()
    return results


@app.task(bind=True, queue='deep_model', name='predict')
def predict(self, model_name, version, max_len, dataset):
    logger = create_logger(LogDir.inference)
    data = json.loads(dataset)

    output = []
    for idx, chunk in enumerate(chunks(data, 32)):
        logger.info(f" ==== batch: {idx} ==== ")
        infer_worker = BertInferenceWorker(
            dataset=chunk,
            model_name=model_name,
            model_version=version,
            url='triton:8000',
            backend='pytorch',
            max_len=max_len,
            chunk_size=len(chunk)
        )
        results = infer_worker.run()
        # print(results)
        output.extend(results.tolist())

    assert len(output) == len(data)

    return json.dumps(output, ensure_ascii=False)
```

- localhost celery

```
from celery import Celery


app = Celery(
    name='bert_celery',
    broker="redis://localhost:6379/0",
    backend="redis://localhost:6379/1"
)

app.conf.task_routes = {
    'app.*': {'queue': 'deep_model'},
}


@app.task(bind=True, queue='deep_model', name='training')
def training(
        self,
        model_name,
        version,
        dataset,
        label_col,
        learning_rate,
        epochs,
        batch_size,
        max_len,
        is_multi_label
):
    pass


@app.task(bind=True, queue='deep_model', name='predict')
def predict(
        self,
        model_name,
        version,
        max_len,
        dataset
):
    pass
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753040/retrieve-task-result-by-id-in-celery

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution of this problem.
First, I thought it might be the error from `Redis`, so I checked the docker log and it showed:

```
WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
```

So I re-configured the `overcommit_memory` yet the problem still wasn't solved.

Then, I tried to add the related task which I wanted to retrieve the task info as well as the results by `from app import predict` in the same script with `AsyncResult` and IT WORKED!

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult 
from app import predict # this is essential

results = AsyncResult(<task_id>)
print(results.state) # if no task imported this may return `DisabledBackend`
print(results.get()) # if no task imported this may return `DisabledBackend`
```

It seems that when celery trying to get the result information, you have to import the **related task** too to let it knows the backend setting. It is kinda a dumb question tho...