# How do you return the result of a completed celery task and store the data in variables?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have two flask modules **app.py** and **tasks.py**.

I set up Celery in tasks.py to complete a selenium webdriver request (which takes about 20 seconds). My goal is to simply return the result of that request to app.py.

Running the Celery worker on another terminal, I can see in the console that the Celery task completes successfully and prints all the data I need from the selenium request. However, now I just want to return the task result to app.py.

How do I obtain the celery worker results data from tasks.py and store each result element as a variable in app.py?

**app.py:**

I define the marketplace and call the task function and request the indexed results:

```
import tasks

marketplace = 'cheddar_block_games'

# This is what I am trying to get back:
price_check = tasks.scope(marketplace[0])
image = tasks.scope(marketplace[1])
```

**tasks.py:**

```
celery = Celery(broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')


 @celery.task()
 def scope(marketplace):
     web.get(f'https://magiceden.io/marketplace/{marketplace}')
     price_check = WebDriverWait(web,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/span/div[2]/div/span[1]"))).text
     image = WebDriverWait(web,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/img")))

     return (price_check, image)
```

Comment: I propose using an "action oriented name" to better describe what fhe task is doing so the next developer and know when they see the task on the queue what it is for?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might be relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760142/9347535

app.py should call the task e.g. using scope.delay or scope.apply_async. You could then fetch the task result with AsyncResult.get():
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#result-backends

Since the task returns a tuple, you can store each variable by unpacking it:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

The result would be something like this:

```
import tasks

marketplace = 'cheddar_block_games'

result = tasks.scope.delay(marketplace)
price_check, image = result.get()
```

Comment: Thank you! Following your code example above worked.

Comment: Forgot to mention for anyone who comes across this, you also need to add a backend. Example:`celery = Celery(broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379', backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')` if testing localhost with redis.