# Retry celery tasks before their countdown

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

we are running Django v1.10 with celery v4.0.2, rabbitMQ v3.5.7 and flower v0.9.1 and are pretty new with celery, rabbitMQ and flower.

There is a function x() which was set to retry after 7 days in case of failure. We have 1000's of instances of x re-queued on production. We have fixed the issue and would like to retry the instances asap.

Is there a way to force the retry before it's scheduled time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a lot of things, I had to solve it by getting the list of scheduled tasks and their arguments and calling the functions in a for loop with the arguments.

There is apparently no way to retry a task manually by design. You have to create another task with the same parameters. This is what I finally did:

```
i = inspect()
scheduled = i.scheduled()
for key in scheduled:
    for element in scheduled[key]:
        reqDict = element['request']
        if reqDict['type']=='module.function':
            module.function.delay(converted_arguments)
            revoke(reqDict['id'], terminate=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a list of the tasks, it's a matter of calling `task.retry(exc=exc)` on each one. [See docs.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying)

Try `celery.task.control.inspect().reserved()` and see if you can filter the tasks that way. [Example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369466/2096883)

You get a task object from its id with this, per [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544611/retrieve-a-task-result-object-given-a-task-id-in-celery)

```
result = MyTask.AsyncResult(task_id)
result.get()
```

Comment: I tried that, but inspect.scheduled() doesn't return task object but dictionary representation of it and thus i cant call task.retry on it. 

I have been trying to find how to get task object from task id but haven't been able to find it. It would be great if you can share an alternative/share how to get task object from its id.

Comment: @PrakharGupta Try `MyTask.AsyncResult()`